# Different packaging with Spring Maven Plugin: Spring + Spark application

Tags: maven, apache-spark, spring-boot, maven-plugin

I have a project which consists of three parts:

- Spring Boot application
- Spark Application
- "Library" used by both of the above (having this library as separate JAR or similar causes quiet a bit of overhead and slowed down the development)

So what I want is a JAR that can be used to run the Spring Boot app (java -jar myapp.jar) as well as the Spark app (java -cp myapp.jar path.to.main.class).
It is also OK to have two JARs - but both would need to be fat JARs (meaning: include dependencies).

What I tried in the pom.xml is this:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>
```

This creates (as expected) a fat JAR that can be used to run the Spring Boot app. But it cannot be used for the Spark app (as the classes and dependencies are somehow repackaged as I understand).

My second try was this:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>repackage</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <classifier>exec</classifier>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

This creates the fat JAR as well plus another JAR just holding the classes that are implemented in my project - but without the dependencies. Therefore the Spark job does not start (as expected).

Any idea how to solve this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I used the same technology stack for an application (Spring- for the web part and Apache Spark for the big data processing). I don't see the case where someone wants to build a fat jar for both the side, Spring + Spark (except the case where inside spark jobs you would use something from Spring). So, the approach that we use is to have to separate Maven module one for the Spring web part and one for the Apache Spark. For the Spring Boot we did not use the spring-boot-maven-plugin, but instead we used the following maven plugins, something like this:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.Application</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludeArtifactIds>integration</excludeArtifactIds>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.Application</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Like this we have a better controller use all the dependencies (e.g: put then in a lib folder and include them in MANIFEST)

For the Spark application you have two option:

- run with spark-submit (personally i don't prefer it)
- use SparkLauncher class from spark_launcher*.jar dependency (calling from web a Spark Job).

Building a fat jar for Spark application with only dependencies used in Spark code is desirable, cause you load only what you truly need. We can use maven-shade-plugin for this:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <includes>
                             // put here what you need to include
                            </includes>
                        </artifactSet>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using maven shade plugin is not encouraged, unless and until there is no other option apart from using the maven shade plugin. Below is the informative link for not to use the shade plugin.

[Downsides of using Shade plugin relocation feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53710931/downsides-of-using-shade-plugin-relocation-feature)

From my perspective for running spark application, spring boot maven plugin is the best option for managing everything, including library dependencies. Even if your application is used as a scheduled job, in which you need to use spark-submit/spark launcher for launching the application.

In other case where your java app using spark and spring both but have controller/api to use the application in that case also spring boot maven plugin is the best one.

There are only 2 types of Challanges when we use spark-submit/spark launcher to launch the application which is created using spring boot maven plugin.

**1. Main Class**

When we package fat jar/uber jar using spring boot maven plugin, it is packging the class files and java libraries in spring way and not the way sprak is expecting it.Inside the uber jar generated by the spring boot maven plugin, we have *boot-inf,meta-inf *and* org* folder.So when we give mainclass in spark submit or spark launcher as a parameter,It will not able to find that class as it will not be able to locate package/path specified in parameter, due to change of structure in jar file.Even after you specify the correct location which is starting with BOOT-INF for main class, it will not work because the way spring launches the application is using differrent main class.

Below is the link which shows main class that should be used for launching the fat jar generated by spring boot maven plugin.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html#appendix.executable-jar.launching

On high level if I inform ,File named as MANIFEST.MF inside the uber jar contains below entries.Where *Main-Class* is the actual main class which is used for initialization of spring related stuff, after which customized main class should get started which is Start-Class entry.

Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: com.mycompany.project.MyApplication

So as a conclusion specifiying main class as "**org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher**" in spark-submit or spark-launcher will resolve our issue for this problem.This will only work if you are using sparing boot maven plugin for packagin the jar.

**External common libraries used in pom.xml+spark installation.**
Another issue which might occure while using spark-submit or launcher application while launching uber jar, packaged using the spring boot maven plugin is jar conflicts.So the problem will be when we package jar using spring boot maven plugin, it is coping depedencies inside BOOT-INF/lib folder, let's say if you are using below depedency in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Now let's say this depedency already exist with differrent version in spark installation, in that case it will give conflict in classes.As it will be an issue of class loader ,its better not to use those which might create conflict due to which application might fail.I have faced this kind of issues related to logger classes or json libraries, as there are multiple json/logger library options are available.As a resolution you can excluded those classes or libraries or you can replace that library with alternative one.